# How can i store different input data from a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Game with the following structure:

```
{
      "name": "Disco Ride",
      "description": "Get ready to groove on a spinning ride with funky beats and dazzling lights.",
      "employees": ["5d713995b721c3bb38c1f5d8", "5d713995b721c3bb38c1f5da"],
      "hours": [
        {
          "opening": "2023-06-07T11:00:00Z",
          "closing": "2023-06-07T21:00:00Z"
        },
        {
          "opening": "2023-06-08T13:00:00Z",
          "closing": "2023-06-08T23:00:00Z"
        }
      ],
      "createdAt": "2023-06-07T15:00:00Z"
    },
}
```

And i have the following GameForm.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import FormGroup from '../UI/FormGroup'
import '../../styles/components/Auth/RegisterForm.css'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { createGame } from '../../slices/gameSlice';
import { fetchEmployees } from '../../slices/employeeSlice';

function GameForm() {

  const { employees: employeesList } = useSelector((state) => state.employees);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchEmployees());
  }, [dispatch]);

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: "",
        description: "",
        employees: [],
        hours: [
          {
            opening: "",
            closing: ""
          }
        ],
      });
    
      console.log(employeesList)
      const { name, description,  hours, employees, photo } = formData;
    
      const onChange = e => {
        const { name, options, multiple } = e.target;

        if (name === "opening" || name === "closing") {
          const updatedHours = [...hours];
          const index = formFields.findIndex((field) => field.name === name);
          updatedHours[index / 2] = {
            ...updatedHours[index / 2],
            [name]: value,
          };

        setFormData({ ...formData, hours: updatedHours });
      
        if (name === "employees") {
          const selectedOptions = Array.from(options)
            .filter(option => option.selected)
            .map(option => option.value);
          setFormData(prevFormData => ({
            ...prevFormData,
            [name]: multiple ? selectedOptions : selectedOptions[0]
          }));
        } else {
          setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: e.target.value });
        }
      }
    };

      const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(createGame(formData));
      }
      

    const formFields = [
        {
          name: "name",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "Name",
          label: "Name",
          value: name,
          onChange: onChange
        },
        {
          name: "description",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "Description",
          label: "Description",
          value: description,
          onChange: onChange
        },
        {
            name: "photo",
            type: "file",
            placeholder: "Game Photo",
            label: "Game Photo",
            value: photo,
            onChange: onChange
           },
        {
         name: "opening",
         type: "datetime-local",
         placeholder: "Opening Hour",
         label: "Opening Hour",
         value: hours[0].opening,
        },
        {
          name: "closing",
          type: "datetime-local",
          placeholder: "Closing Hour",
          label: "Closing Hour",
          value: hours[0].closing,
         },
        {
         name: "employees",
         type: "select",
         placeholder: "Employees",
         label: "Employees",
         value: employees,
         options: employeesList.filter(employee => employee.type === 'manager').map((employee) => ({
          value: employee._id,
          label: `${employee.name} ${employee.lastName}`,
         })),
         multiple: true,
         onChange: onChange
        },
      ]
      
      console.log(formData)
      
  return (
    <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh', width: '100%'}}>
      <form className='form_container' onSubmit={onSubmit} encType='multipart/form-data' >
          {formFields.map((field) => (
              <FormGroup key={field.name} {...field} />
          ))}
          <button type="submit">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default GameForm
```

I map the fields of the form, but i am having issues to store the data.

The first issue is in the hours.

I select a date an hour but in the select the value isnt showing.

It seems that i am never selecting it an keeps showing `dd/mm/yyyy --:--`

Instead of for example: `02/06/2023 09:25`

And then i am having issues selecting more than one employee. Which i am able to select more than one employee but to achieve that i have to do ctrl + click.

I also have this warning which i dont understand so i don´t know if its related to my form fields or what.

```
 You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
```

But i am certain that the issue on how to send the opening and closing hours and select several employees have to do with my onChange function.